# REGEX. How to get the numbers AFTER the white space not including the white space

Tags: regex

EXAMPLE:

```
C224234242233242 343 3243
```

need to get 343 3243. Not including the starting space.

I tried `\s(.*)`, but no luck.

Comment: try removing the period ".", something like: \d+\s*\d+

Comment: nope, still adds the first space

Comment: The part after the space is in the capture group, not the whole match. Did you get the capture group?

Comment: You could also use a lookbehind.

Comment: What language are you using? Show the code that tries to get what you want.

Comment: i'm using javascript on this testing site - https://regexr.com/

Comment: You're only looking at the highlighted text, but if you hover it, it shows that the 'match' is actually just the number (assuming you'd use `\d*` instead of `.*`) - instead of asking questions about the results of an online application, you're generally better off showing how you plan to use something in code.

Comment: the results are exactly what im needing. This is just an intro course and im having trouble doing one of the last questions. The result is all i need in this case.

Comment: `^[^\s]+\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)`

Comment: that grabs the whole block of numbers start to finish lol @ e2-e4

Comment: That gives you in matches[1] `343` and matches[2] `3243`... lol

Comment: i just tried it, its not getting '343 3243', it outputs the whole string of numbers

Comment: nvm that worked, thank you!!

Comment: You could use `\b\d+` see https://regex101.com/r/AwStDH/1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only (alphanumeric) (number) (number), then `^[A-Z\d]+ (\d+ \d+)$`.

Breaking it down, `^` and `$` mark the beginning and end of the line (by default), it's good practice to use them. `[A-Z\d]+` is any letter or number, repeated 1 or more times. Then we capture two sets of one or more numbers (`\d+`) separated by a space.

Comment: tried that just now. Doesn't work unfortunately. output doesnt grab anything.

Comment: I tested it on your regexer site and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`.*? (.*)` works fine in the given example.

It just grabs everything after the first whitespace.

```js
const regex = /.*? (.*)/
const str = `C224234242233242 343 3243`
console.log(regex.exec(str)[1])
```